# Is using structs with virtual inheritance a bad idea when reading from EEPROM? (Arduino)

Tags: c++11, casting, arduino-uno, virtual-inheritance, eeprom

I've run into a strange problem where if I load my data structure from EEPROM it casts it incorrectly. But, if I have both my function calls to the function responsible for saving the data structure and the function responsible for reading the data structure it casts the data into my structure successfully.

I've played around with the problem a bit and I've noticed that the data saved and the data read from the EEPROM is always correct if you read it as `uint8_t`. But for some reason it fails to cast the data into my data structure (`BareKeyboardKey2`) when the save function is not used in the program and we only read the data from the EEPROM.

**The following structure is what I believe causes the problem:**

```
// testStruct.h

struct IKey2
{
    int pin;
};

struct BareKeyboardKey2 : virtual IKey2
{
    int keyCode;
    BareKeyboardKey2() {}
    BareKeyboardKey2(int _pin, int _keyCode)
    {
        pin = _pin;
        keyCode = _keyCode;
    }
};
```

**Example output of when I first call SaveStruct then LoadStruct. (The data I save to EEPROM is a `BareKeyboardKey2(2, 4)`:**

> Reading: 0x68 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x2 0x0
> pin: 2, keycode: 4

as you can see it casts the `BareKeyboardKey2` correctly, but...
Here is an **example output of when ONLY LoadStruct is called (and the same data from the previous example is stored on the EEPROM):**

> Reading: 0x68 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x2 0x0
> pin: -18248, keycode: 4

As you can see the data read from the EEPROM (i.e `0x68 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x2 0x0`) is the same between both examples, but in the latter example it fails to properly cast the data into a BareKeyboardKey2 (`pin: -18248, keycode: 4`).

**I have found that if I change the structure into the following it works regardless if I use `SaveStruct` and `LoadStruct` consequently or only use `LoadStruct`:**

```
// testStruct.h
struct IKey2
{
};

struct BareKeyboardKey2 : virtual IKey2
{
    int pin;
    int keyCode;
    BareKeyboardKey2() {}
    BareKeyboardKey2(int _pin, int _keyCode)
    {
        pin = _pin;
        keyCode = _keyCode;
    }
};
```

I also found that if I move both variables into the IKey2 like this...:

```
struct IKey2
{
    int pin;
    int keyCode;
};

struct BareKeyboardKey2 : virtual IKey2
{
    BareKeyboardKey2() {}
    BareKeyboardKey2(int _pin, int _keyCode)
    {
        pin = _pin;
        keyCode = _keyCode;
    }
};
```

... this causes the program to cast both variables wrong. Example output: `pin: -18248, keycode: -18248`

What is causing this behavior and what can I do to make it consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I'm not 100% sure it's right, but this is my theory...

When saving down non-POD structs as bytes to an EEPROM it does not save down the connection between the main struct and the virtual object connected to the struct. Thus, the data is the same, but if you look into the object using a debugger (in my case gdb) you will see that the virtual ptr that connects the main struct and the virtual object is an invalid pointer. Although, the rest of the data that is originally present in the main struct is still intact.

So in my case to solve the problem I converted my struct into a POD type by removing the virtual inheritance from my struct. Instead, I used a "Has a" relationship, and so far my data is reading correctly from the EEPROM regardless of the different cases used above.